# Verify my proof that e is irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, solution-verification

I just want some confirmation that my proof that $e$ is irrational is valid. Please offer any comments on what I could do better/formatting tips, and point out any logical errors, no matter how small. Thanks!

We need to prove that $e$ is irrational. We proceed to prove by contradiction.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that there exist integers $p$, $q$ such that $p$ and $q$ are integers. We first prove that $e$ cannot be an integer by using the fact that $$e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$

We see that $$1+\frac{1}{1!}<1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\ldots<1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$$ since it can be shown that $n!>2^n$ for all $n>3$. This means that $2<e<3$ and thus $e$ cannot be an integer. This means that $q\neq 1$. Since $e=p/q$, we can write $$\frac{p}{q}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$ If we multiply both sides by $q!$, we notice that we get $$p(q-1)!=q!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{q}\frac{q!}{n!}+\sum_{n=q+1}^{\infty}\frac{q!}{n!}$$ We notice that since $p$ and $q$ are integers, the left side must be an integer. Now, looking at the right side, we see that the first term is an integer, since every factor in the denominator cancels out with some factor in $q!$, since $n\leq q$ in the first term. However, the right sum simplifies to $$\sum_{n=q+1}^{\infty}\frac{q!}{n!}=\frac{1}{q+1}+\frac{1}{(q+1)(q+2)}+\cdots<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(q+1)^k}$$ We see that this is an infinite geometric series with sum $$\frac{\frac{1}{q+1}}{1-\frac{1}{q+1}}=\frac{1}{q}$$ and since $q\neq 1$, we see that this sum must be less than $1$, so it cannot be an integer. This means we have an integer and a non-integer summing to an integer, a contradiction. This means our assumption must have been wrong, and $e$ must be irrational, completing the proof.

Comment: Looks good! You can actually omit the part where you first show that $q\ne1$, since you have a strict inequality at the end.

Comment: This proof is very similar to the second proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational#:~:text=The%20number%20e%20was%20introduced,the%20quotient%20of%20two%20integers.

Comment: This is a very standard proof of irrationality of $e$ and also the very first one I read.